# How can I import the const data from another file using Promise (React)

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise, react-map-gl

I am trying to import data from another file into my React component. The data is acquired via an asynchronous function resolving to the data.

However I am getting an error when trying to map over the test data in the consuming component. I think this is something to do with the fact that my getter returns a promise.

The component renders fine if I just inline the data as a `const` in the same file.

JS file (export)

```
 export const test = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(data());
        });
     
    };
    
    const data = () => {
        return [
            {
                name: "tom",
                car: "tesla"
            },
            {
                name: "sam",
                car: "honda"
            },
            {
                name: "may",
                car: ["toyota", "BMW"],
            },
            
        ];
    };
```

Jsx file (import)

```
import { test } from "./test"

function List() {

  return (
    <div className="food">
      
      {test.map((value,index) => (
         <div key={index}>
           <p>{value.name}</p>
           <p>{value.car}</p>
           </div>    
         ))}
    </div>   
  ) 
}
export default List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test` isn't an array variable, it's a function that returns a Promise object.

To fix your problem follow these steps:

1. Declare state `data` and initial its value to `[]`.
2. Add`useEffect` hook to fetch your data.
3. Use state `data` to render your html.

   ```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
   import { test } from './test';

   function List() {
     const [data, setData] = useState([]);

     useEffect(() => {
       test().then((res) => setData(res));
     }, []);

     return (
       <div className="food">
         {data.map((value, index) => (
           <div key={index}>
             <p>{value.name}</p>
             <p>{value.car}</p>
           </div>
         ))}
       </div>
     );
   }
   export default List;
   ```

This is a simple demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2pmxgb?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 0):

[Soufiane Boutahlil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11498568/soufiane-boutahlil) answer is correct, Furthermore if you want you can also make a custom hook for functions that returns promises like so

```
function useAsync(promise, defaultValue) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(defaultValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    promise.then((promiseData) => setData(promiseData));
  }, [promise]);

  return data;
}
```

then in your code you can do this

```
function List() { {
  const testData = useAsync(test(), []); // empty array in the second parameter can be of type any
  return (
    <div>
      {testData.map((value, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{value.name}</p>
          <p>{value.car}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1btahu